# Flutter: Stop playing video in list view when another video is started

Tags: flutter, dart

i am using Better Player (https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) to create several video players in list view.

```
ListView.builder(
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
itemCount: awaitedContents!.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  Content content = awaitedContents[index];
 ...
  } else if (content.type == 'VIDEO') {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 9 / 16,
      child: VideoContent(content.value, content.image,
          content.videoSubtitle, subtitlesEnabled),
    );
  }
```

How can I stop one Video player from playing when users starts another one?